# amCharts dynamic Stacked Column, add urlField or ID to JSON

Tags: php, json, amcharts

I am generating a graph using data loader. My JSON data looks similar to this.

```
 {
        "Month": 1,
        "District1": 2.6,
        "District2": 5.7,
        "District3": 6.2,
        "District4": 7.3,

    }, {
        "Month": 2,
        "District1": 4.6,
        "District2": 5.7,
        "District3": 2.2,
        "District4": 6.3,
        "District5": 4.3,
        "District7": 1.3,

    }
```

In my JavaScrit i am using this code to generate graphs loeded from a PHP file.

```
  for ( var key in chart.dataProvider[ 0 ] ) {
            if ( chart.dataProvider[ 0 ].hasOwnProperty( key ) && key != chart.categoryField ) {

var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
              graph.valueField = key;
              graph.type = "column";
              graph.title = key;
              graph.lineThickness = 0;

              graph.urlField =?????????????????????
              graph.urlTarget ="_blank";
              graph.labelColor = "#cccccc";
              graph.connect = false;
              graph.fillAlphas = 0.8;
              graph.balloonFunction = adjustBalloonText;
              graph.labelText =  key;
              chart.addGraph( graph );

            }

        }
```

The data is dynamic some moths there are 15 objects some only 12.

I want to add a link to every district or id so i can generate new Chart. 
How do i add that to the JSON string. I have tried to do this with objects 
like this.

```
{
"Month":1
"District1": {"value":1, "url":"url.php?id=1", "id":1}
"District2": {"value":2, "url":"url.php?id=2", "id":2}
}
```

I couldn't assign a object to **graph.valueField = key;**

Is this possible to solve? The on click event just returns the month index not info about the graph "ID".

Hope someone can help me to solve this. I have been trying for hours without any luck.

Best regards

Martin

Answer (score 1):

You should "flatten" your `dataProvider`, as amCharts' `urlField` and `valueField` cannot refer to a key inside a nested object. So, instead of:

```
{
  "Month":1
  "District1": {"value":1, "url":"url.php?id=1", "id":1}
  "District2": {"value":2, "url":"url.php?id=2", "id":2}
}
```

Try to output something like this instead:

```
 {

  "Month":1

  "Dist1Value": 1,
  "Dist1Url": "url.php?id=1",
  "Dist1id": 1,

  "Dist2Value": 2,
  "Dist2Url": "url.php?id=2",
  "Dist2id": 2

}
```

I would also change your `for key ... in` loop to a normal `for` loop to loop over predefined districts (I assume you know how many districts there can be).

```
var amount_districts = 12;

for(var i = 0; i < amount_districts.length; i++){

  // create a graph for each of our districts

  var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph.type = "column";
    graph.title = "District " + (i+1);
    graph.valueField = "Dist" + (i+1) + "Value";
    graph.UrlField = "Dist" + (i+1) + "Url";
    // ... etc

  // finally, add this graph to the chart
  chart.addGraph(graph);

}
```

If it happens there are no data items for "District 10", the graph will just not show (however, it will show in the legend).